# Type.GetType() once return type, once return null

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I know there are some posts about Type.GetType() reutrning null, but my problem is, that I have .dll module and use it in desktop version written in c#. This module load configuration from xml, deserialize it and return me filled object. On desktop version it's working right.

Now want to add this into our API running on .NET Core. So I use the same .dll file and use the same method load as on desktop.

In XML we also store Assembly Qualified Name (namespace.class, assembly, version, culture, publickeyToken). On desktop version we create configuration for example in version 1.2.3.4, than make some changes on this .dll, change version to 1.2.3.5 and we are still able to load configuration. But if try to do the same in API, I'm not able to do that, only if in XML is the same version as currently assembly version. Cannot load config with lower version.

I found problem on this row, where typeArgumentName is Assembly Qualified Name.

```
Type.GetType(typeArgumentName)
```

If I debug this code with desktop app, it works fine. If debug it with API and change typeArgumenName version to current .dll version, it works. If don't change it, it returns null.

My question is, why it's working on desktop version and return me right type and why it returns me null when use it with API.

Comment: It seems like that the assembly you want to access does exist but hasnt been initialised yet when you want to get its type.

Comment: I don't think so. In the .dll file is object, that load and save config, but also the config object/s. So in my assembly is object config and than configLoader that try to load this config.

Answer (score 0):

This could be happen due to using incompatible C# libraries. I mean if you will use libraries of desktop application into your web API project then it can happen because sometime web version doesn't recognize desktop dlls.

Comment: In this case it wont work always. But it does work for stored values with the same assembly version as have used dll. Problem is when I increase dll version (there can be no changes in code).